# Formal article to read that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is properly contained in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

First let $\mathcal{B},\mathcal{L}$ be the Borel and Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebras, respectively. I've been searching for my final project of real analysis on how to prove that $\mathcal{B}\varsubsetneq\mathcal{L}$ and I think i got the general idea of the prove:

You take the cantor function $\mathit{c}:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and construct $f=\mathit{c}+I$ ($I$ is the identity function), then you analyze $f$ and conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

After that, you observe that every lebesgue measurable set of non-zero Lebesgue measure contains a Lebesgue non-measurable subset and that this homomorphism $f$ "sends" Borel sets to Borel sets (most people mention a more general result of this and apply it to $f$).

We take $f(\mathcal{C})$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set, which is a Lorel set (then Lebesgue measurable, of measure $0$),and show that $f(\mathcal{C})$ is a Borel set, then Lebesgue measurable of measure 1, so we know there exist $K\subset f(\mathcal{C})$ not Lebesgue measurable.

But $f^{-1}(K)\subset \mathcal{C}$, so it's measurable of measure $0$ but not a Borel set, because otherwise it would make $K$ to be Borel too, reaching a contradiction.

My question is if there's a formal article I could use as a reference for my project, since I've only found blogs and informal articles where the people don't exactly justify all these steps.

Comment: When you write "homomorphism", what you really mean is "homEomorphism".

Comment: The proof I knew was to describe Borel sets via transfinite recursion, observe that there are $\beth_1$, and then observe that all subsets of Cantor's set are Lebesgue measurable (and therefore there are $\beth_2$ Lebesgue measurable sets).

Comment: The google search ["measurable" + "not Borel" + "Lebesgue"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22measurable%22+%22not+Borel%22+%22Lebesgue%22) brings up a lot things worth looking at. For specific published references, since I tend to give lots of these in my answers/comments, try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22measurable%22+%22not+Borel%22+%22Lebesgue%22+%22Renfro%22+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for example the Appendix C of Frank Burk's *Lebesgue Measure and Integration: An Introduction*, available online at the [Wiley Online library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118032732.app3).